# Wait for Specific Text to Appear Using VBA Object "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0" or Similar

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code using Internet Explorer which allows the page to load until the word "Fair Value" appears in the final HTML (which I then want to extract):

```
Dim t As Date,
Dim fTextFound as Boolean
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 3 '<==Adjust wait time
 
myUrl = "https://finbox.com/NASDAQGS:AMZN/models/dcf-growth-exit-10yr"
Set oIE = New InternetExplorer

oIE.navigate myUrl
oIE.Visible = True

Do
Loop Until oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
oIE.Refresh

While oIE.Busy Or oIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    HTMLDoc.Body.innerHTML = oIE.document.Body.innerHTML
    sPageHTML = HTMLDoc.Body.innerHTML
    If InStr(LCase(sPageHTML), "fair value") > 0 Then ftextFound = True
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop While fTextFound= False

If fTextFound= True Then ......Do the rest
```

Since I believe that Internet Explorer will no longer be supported in Windows 11, can someone provide code that will mimic this functionality using "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0"or similar in VBA?

I do have Selenium installed, so similar code for that would also be acceptable.

The idea is that it is a dynamic page which takes a few seconds to completely load, so just getting the .responseText is not sufficient.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page?

Comment: If you want to mimic the approach using IE, you are best off using Selenium, request made using XMLHTTP are static and do not load any script (which is most likely where your dynamic content comes from) like a browser does.

Comment: I've added an example of a url I'm interested in gathering info from,: myUrl = "https://finbox.com/NASDAQGS:AMZN/models/dcf-growth-exit-10yr"